# What algorithm would be most efficient when trying to find the nearest city given a set of coordinates?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataset which contains the longitude and latitude of the 1000 largest US cities. I'm designing an API which returns the user's nearest city, given an input of the user's longitude/latitude.

What is the most efficient algorithm I can use to calculate the nearest city? I know that I can use the haversine formula to calculate the distance between the user's coordinate and each cities, but it seems inefficient to have to do this for all 1000 cities. I've previously used a k-d tree to solve nearest neighbour problems on a plane - is there a similar solution that can be used in the context of a globe?

Edit: keeping this simple - distance I'm looking for is as the crow flies. Not taking roads or routes into account at this stage.

Comment: Nearest by distance as the crow flies? By road network distance? By travel time? These answers could be quite different.

Comment: Simply as the crow flies - nothing more complicated

Comment: Converting Lat/Lon coordinates to 3d spacial coordinates might help you.

Comment: Hmm, only 1000, and this is for an API that sounds like querying a single location... does that really need the most efficient algorithm?

Comment: It does matter :)

Comment: kd-tree / balltree work perfectly with haversine, so that is the go-to solution, and a great jump from a naive search. Change the matric to haversine. Be sure to convert lat/long to rads and you are good to go

Comment: There's no capital H to "haversine". It's a common noun, not someone's name.

Comment: The USA are pretty flat. It doesn't matter that they're on a globe. You can put them in a quadtree using (longitude, latitude) like it was (x, y).

Comment: you can indeed make US flat, know there are projections that work better than just take the lat/longs as x/y, which respect distances more.  pyproj has implemented a few

Comment: I need to take into account the curvature of the earth.

Comment: Then try the haversine with kdtree/balltree

Comment: @Jay My point is, you can use the haversine formula when computing the exact distances, but use the approximation "the US are flat" when storing the points in the quadtree.

Comment: @Stef No - because what if the user input was in England or Poland? Approximation to a flat US then doesn't work if I need to take into account points that aren't within the US.

Comment: *"Edit: None of these solutions offered the correct answer and this question should just be deleted."* <<< There is no such thing as "the correct answer". The only way to find the most appropriate solution for your exact problem is to come to your lab and test solutions on your data. You're the only one in the position to do that. All the answers posted here make sense for your question; and which answer can lead to the best solution to your problem is for you to find.

Comment: And even if someone posted an answer here with an approach that could lead to this most appropriate solution, it wouldn't be obvious in foresight. You'd still have work to do, finding the exact best way to implement this approach. No one can do this work for you. It is still an interesting question, and interesting answers have been given, and it wouldn't be particularly wise to dismiss them just because they don't immediately appear perfect and shiny.

Comment: @Jay *"No - because what if the user input was in England or Poland? Approximation to a flat US then doesn't work if I need to take into account points that aren't within the US."* Is that a guess, or did you actually try? As far as I can tell, the US state which is closer to the UK according to a flat approximation is Maine, and the US state which is actually closer to the UK in true distance is also Maine. So, it looks to me like the approximation holds pretty well.

Comment: Just make sure you cut Earth along a line opposite to the US, so that Japan appears west of the US and Europe appears east. The point of the approximation is not to give the exact distance, it is just to store data in the quadtree. The closest point according to true Earth geometry will not be ***the*** closest point according to flat Earth approximation, but it will be ***one of the*** closest points, so the quadtree will help you by having to check only reasonable candidates, which makes the whole thing much more efficient than having to check all candidates.

Comment: @Stef this is not correct

Comment: Balltree with haversine metric not 'correct' enough? It is accurate up to about 1%, with fast & simple implementation. I can understand for some reason you cannot make it work, but please provide more info why some solutions are not helping you, instead of just throws them all away. This is against stack's values.

Answer (score 2):

First, https://gisgeography.com/python-libraries-gis-mapping/ has a bunch of Python libraries for dealing with geography.  Or you can push the problem to a database, for example with https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index, and solve it there.  I'd recommend looking at those ideas before wrapping your own.

That said, in the past what I've done for US cities is to stick everything into a lat/long 2-D structure, take the city, construct a lat/long bounding box (using the fact that lat/long can be turned into approximate distances), use that to return a handful of candidate closest cities, and then do the hard calculation from the candidate cities.  I've personally seen a database successfully perform this calculation several hundred thousands times/hour while handling a lot of other traffic.  And this was 20 years ago - I'd expect more now.

For a worldwide dataset I'd put the cities into a handful of such structures, with different choices of poles for lat/long.  For a given city I'd pick the axis which puts the city farthest from either pole, then proceed as before.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the map into squares that do not overlap and they cover the whole US map (i.e., you will have a grid). You will number the squares using the coordinates of their upper left corner (i.e., each one will have a unique ID) and you will do a preprocessing where each city will be assigned with the ID of the square where it belongs. You will find the square where the user lies into and then you will check only the cities that lie into this square and the ones that are one step from this (total: 9 squares). If these are empty of cities, you will check the ones that are two steps of it etc. In this way, on average you will check much less cities to find the closest

Answer (score 1):

This answer is very similar to that of **ckc**.

First, spilt the 1000 cities in 2 groups : a big one located located between Canada and Mexico and the few others cities located outside this rectangle (i.e Alaska, Hawai, ...).

When processing coordinates, check if they belong to the small group : in this case, no optimisation needed.

To optimize the other case, you may divide the map in rectangles (example 5°lat x 7° lon) and associate to each rectangle the list of cities belonging to each rectangle.

To find the nearest city, consider the rectangle R containing the point.
Compute the distance to the cities of the rectangle.
Process the 8 rectangles adjacent to R by computing the distance of the point to each rectangle : you may then eliminate the adjacent rectangles whose distance is greater than the best distance already found.

Iterate the process to a next level, i.e. the next crown (rectangles located on the outside of the area composed of 5x5 rectangles whose center is R).

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion in the discussion, here is an example using Haversine, with `sklearn`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

cities = pd.read_json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Miserlou/c5cd8364bf9b2420bb29/raw/2bf258763cdddd704f8ffd3ea9a3e81d25e2c6f6/cities.json")

cities_gps = cities[['latitude','longitude']].values
cities_radians = np.radians(cities_gps)
```

The above code loads 1000 cities I found on some git. Pandas is just being used to parse the JSON, it is not needed to calculate.

You can build a tree as follows (leafsize can be tweaked a little, has minor effect)

```
tree = BallTree(cities_radians, leaf_size=15, metric='haversine')
```

Now say we have 10000 lat/longs, you can query as follows:

```
random_geo = np.random.normal(loc=(30,-80), scale=(8,8), size=(10000,2))
random_geo_radians = np.radians(random_geo)
```

If you just query 1, make sure not to re-build the tree for each query. That probably takes more time than query for just 1 lat/long pair. SO keep the tree alive and fire queries at it.

```
distances, idx = tree.query( random_geo_radians, k=1)
```

The `distances` contains the unit circle distance, you need to convert to miles/km by multiplying with the earth radius. The mean radius of the  USA would be best.

You could get the names with

```
cities.city[ idx[:,0] ]
```

Comment: The word "haversine" doesn't take a capital h. It's a common noun, not a proper noun. It's a variation of "sine" from trigonometry.

Comment: Thanks for this. One thought - should ```tree = BallTree(cities_gps, leaf_size=15, metric='haversine')``` actually use cities_radians instead of cities_gps?

Comment: yes - you need convert them to radians indeed. Also to query.  Similar to example on https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances.html